# magento2 one step checkout page payment error

Tags: magento2, error, payment-methods, payment-gateway, onestepcheckout

one step checkout page

When Enter debit card details then below error display

"There is an error in payment processing.Error Message From Payment Gateway is Call Voice Center"

So help me.

Comment: have you verified the payment gateway credentials configured correctly? and please raise ticket to the respected module provider?

Comment: please verify exception logs and system logs u will get some information so that it will help you